# Invalid data stored in Delimited Text after running ADF Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to store data from an input to csv file in blob storage via ADF data flow. The pipeline ran successfully. However on checking the csv file, I see some invalid data included. Here are the settings of Delimited Text and Sink. Please let me know what I am missing?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and repeat the error.

The error is caused by that all the csv files in the `csv/test` folder have different schema.

Even if the pipeline runs with no error, but the data in to the single file will has the error.

In Data Factory, when we try to merge more files to one, or copy data from more files to single, the files in the folder must have the same schema.

Note that please using `wildcard paths` to filter all the csv files:

[image]

For example, I have two csv files which have same schema in the container:
[image]

Source dataset preview:

[image]

Only if the source dataset preview is correct, the output file also will be correct.